# How to actually install/fix addons on tor?

Tags: linux, add-on

I am (mostly) aware of the privacy-compromising implications of installing addons to tbb, to mitigate that I have compartmentalized my habits a bit (diff VMs with diff tbb setups going through a tor-proxy). That said I have been trying to set one up as a "comfortable n casual" browser, javascript totally off but with addons like ad blocking, session manager, firegestures, etc.

The catch seems to be that very few addons work properly, or at all, on the tor browser (7.0a4 in my case). A big issue is many addons just disapearing, I can see them and access options via the config:addons tab but they are non-existant anywhere else, not on any toolbars not when I go to customize nada.For example session manager is one of them, it actually seemed to work kinda once, that is showed up in the toorbar but disapeared when I restarted the browser, then (since I could access the options via the config:addon tab) I tried setting up its hotkeys and accessing it that way but again, nada.

Is there something that needs to be set to make tor more amenable to addons? so far only about half of the addons I installed are accessible/work.